# Add Windows authentication in .NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, windows-authentication

I'm new in .NET (Core) 5 and I'm trying to add Windows authentication as I had in previous versions in the `web.config` file:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow roles="Group1" />
    <allow roles="Group2" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

In `launchSettings.json` in my .NET Core application, I did the following changes:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:47743",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
},
```

But don't know how to define:

```
<allow roles="Group1"/>
```

in `launchSettings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your startup.cs file.

Official doc: [Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Group1",
         policy => policy.RequireRole("Group1"));
});
```